# ORDS does not connect with database from browser

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-ords

When I try to get http://localhost:8080/ords/ , it gives me:

```
URLMappingNotFoundException [statusCode=404, reasons=[The request could not be assigned to any database. 
Check if the request URL is correct and if the URLs to the database mappings have been configured correctly]...
```

From the Operations department they've installed ORDS 19.4 in standalone mode, not APEX, on a development machine.
They sent me their file ords_params.properties.

On my own, I have run ORDS from SQL Developer, on my local machine.

I have opened REST Data Services Administration with the user `ords_admin`, and entered the Global Connection from TNS, and Default Password for ORDS_PUBLIC_USER, as specified in the parameters file.

If I validate through Test Configuration, it indicates that the configuration has been carried out successfully.

I select Upload Settings for the changes to upload to ORDS, and so they'll be reflected in defaults.xml.

I have not specified any connection in Database Values, so it hasn't connection pool.
The scheme is REST enabled. The connection to the database is via TNS

Following is the execution log, and the files `tnsnames.ora`, `ords_params.properties`, `defaults.xml`, `standalone.properties` and `url-mapping.xml`.

File: tnsnames.ora

```
DECORP5 = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=exahost.gobe.pri) (PORT=1521) ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=decorp5) ) 
  )
```

File: ORDS Log

```
D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\SQLDEVELOPER\jdk\jre\bin\java -Duser.language=es -Duser.country=ES -jar D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\ords.war configdir D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion
2020-04-21T09:05:48.748Z INFO   Defina config.dir en D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion en: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\ords.war
D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>
D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\SQLDEVELOPER\jdk\jre\bin\java -Duser.language=es -Duser.country=ES -jar D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\ords.war standalone --parameterFile D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\params\sqldev_ords_params.properties
2020-04-21T09:05:55.067Z INFO   Usuario creado: ords_admin en archivo: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion\ords\credentials
2020-04-21T09:05:55.100Z INFO   Usuario creado: ords_dev en archivo: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion\ords\credentials
2020-04-21 11:05:56.356:INFO::main: Logging initialized @4022ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2020-04-21 11:05:56.584:INFO:oeju.TypeUtil:main: JVM Runtime does not support Modules
2020-04-21T09:05:56.774Z INFO   HTTP and HTTP/2 cleartext listening on host: localhost port: 8080
2020-04-21T09:05:56.828Z INFO   The document root is serving static resources located in: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion\ords\standalone\doc_root
2020-04-21 11:05:57.269:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.24.v20191120; built: 2019-11-22T11:09:44.612Z; git: 8b8c80157294e38f81ef8ea2358a0c49bf5db918; jvm 1.8.0_212-b10
2020-04-21 11:05:57.292:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-04-21 11:05:57.292:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-04-21 11:05:57.293:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2020-04-21T09:05:57.790Z INFO   No pools configured yet
2020-04-21T09:05:57.901Z INFO   Oracle REST Data Services initialized
Oracle REST Data Services version : 19.4.0.r3521226
Oracle REST Data Services server info: jetty/9.4.24.v20191120

2020-04-21 11:05:58.350:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@35a50a4c{/ords,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-04-21 11:05:58.351:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@3439f68d{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-04-21 11:05:58.397:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@b9b00e0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-04-21 11:05:58.398:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @6064ms
2020-04-22T07:29:33.891Z INFO   reloaded pools: []
```

File: ords_params.properties

```
db.connectionType=tns
db.tnsDirectory=/network/admin
db.tnsAliasName=decorp5
rest.services.ords.add=true
schema.tablespace.default=SYSAUX
schema.tablespace.temp=TEMP
user.public.password=ordsdesa1ublic
user.tablespace.default=SYSAUX
user.tablespace.temp=TEMP
bequeath.connect=false
ords.admin.password=oracle
ords.admin.username=ords_admin
ords.sqldev.password=oracle
ords.sqldev.username=ords_dev
restEnabledSql.active = true
plsql.gateway.add=false
rest.services.apex.add=false
standalone.mode=true
standalone.http.port=8080
standalone.use.https=false
migrate.apex.rest=false
```

File: standalone.properties

```
jetty.port=8080
standalone.context.path=/ords
standalone.doc.root=D\:\\app\\my_user\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\ords\\configuracion\\ords\\standalone\\doc_root
standalone.scheme.do.not.prompt=true
standalone.static.context.path=/i
standalone.static.do.not.prompt=true
```

File: defaults.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
    <properties>
    <comment>
    <   Listener Administration
    <   Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.1.247.2212
    <   Last Update: Wed Apr 22 12:13:34 CEST 2020
    </comment>
    <entry key="db.password">@05D9AD8E979160A32...</entry>
    <entry key="db.connectionType">tns</entry>
    <entry key="db.hostname"/>
    <entry key="db.port">1521</entry>
    <entry key="db.tnsAliasName">DECORP5</entry>
    <entry key="db.tnsDirectory">D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.DriverType">thin</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.InitialLimit">3</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MinLimit">1</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MaxLimit">10</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MaxStatementsLimit">10</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.InactivityTimeout">1800</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.statementTimeout">900</entry>
    <entry key="security.inclusionList"/>
    <entry key="security.exclusionList"/>
    <entry key="security.disableDefaultExclusionList">false</entry>
    <entry key="security.validationFunctionType">plsql</entry>
    <entry key="security.requestValidationFunction"/>
    <entry key="security.maxEntries">2000</entry>
    <entry key="security.verifySSL">false</entry>
    <entry key="cache.caching">false</entry>
    <entry key="cache.procedureNameList"/>
    <entry key="cache.type">lru</entry>
    <entry key="cache.maxEntries">500</entry>
    <entry key="cache.expiration">7</entry>
    <entry key="cache.duration">days</entry>
    <entry key="cache.directory">/tmp/apex/cache</entry>
    <entry key="procedure.preProcess"/>
    <entry key="procedure.postProcess"/>
    <entry key="misc.defaultPage">apex</entry>
    <entry key="apex.docTable">FLOWS_FILES.WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$</entry>
    <entry key="apex.extensions"/>
    <entry key="log.procedure">false</entry>
    <entry key="debug.output">console</entry>
    <entry key="debug.printDebugToScreen">true</entry>
    <entry key="error.keepErrorMessages">true</entry>
    <entry key="log.logging">false</entry>
    <entry key="status.statistics">true</entry>
    <entry key="apex.excel2collection">false</entry>
    <entry key="apex.excel2collection.onecollection">true</entry>
    <entry key="apex.excel2collection.useSheetName">false</entry>
    <entry key="apex.excel2collection.name"/>
    <entry key="sqldev.name">Configuración de Administración</entry>
    <entry key="sqldev.description">Administración de los servicios REST a desarrollar en la instancia corporativa DECORP5.</entry>
    <entry key="sqldev.version">19.2.1.247.2212</entry>
    <entry key="restEnabledSql.active">true</entry>
    <entry key="jdbc.MaxConnectionReuseCount">1000</entry>
    <entry key="cache.monitorInterval">60</entry>
    <entry key="misc.compress"/>
    </properties>
```

File: url-mapping.xml

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <pool-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apex/pool-config"/>
```

Thank you very much for taking the issue.

Comment: If you don't have apex configured, you're supposed to get a 404 at /ords ... There's no ords 'Home Page: mapped to that url. You need to rest enable a schema and publish a rest service, then call it

Comment: Also, when you started ords, did you pass the tns directory as shiwn in the release notes?

Comment: I passed it in parameters.properties, as /network/admin. Should I pass the complete route?

Comment: I'll try to publish some rest service before and later commen you

Comment: passing ords properties in is for the installer only, once you're ready to run, you need to pass in the path to the tns file via a jvm flag, i.e. java -Doracle.net.tns_admin=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin -jar ords.war